# PHP reading from JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I am encountering this weird problem where it runs fine on my desktop PC but not on my mobile or any other PC.

I am getting this JSON String from an API

```
{"boqqinu":{"id":21842692,"name":"BoQqinu","profileIconId":642,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1396885332000}}
```

and i am using cURL to get this data and decoding it using php function;

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $result = utf8_encode($result);
    $obj = json_decode($result, true);

    $statuscode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($obj);
    echo $obj[$sumNameWeb]['id'];
    echo $obj[$sumNameWeb]['summonerLevel'];
```

however the last 2 echo shows nothing on my mobile/friend pc but shows their value on my PC...
I am not sure what is wrong.. how is this even possible?

Edit- The var dump echos all the data on my pc and my friends pc without a problem..

Comment: What is the value of `$sumNameWeb`?

Comment: in this case, it should be "boqqinu"

Comment: Maybe echo that out, to ensure the values are the same on both your PC and friends?

Comment: How exactly you are using this code ? I mean how you are using in mobile ? Here, nothing is mobile related code, only server side.

Comment: it is returning Boqqinu with capital B, maybe thats the problem? its a web application both mobile and pc are using these

Comment: Yes, that will be the problem. Case sensitivity.

Comment: i guess that was the problem... but it is weird since it is running on my desktop without a problem lol

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the mobile browser is submitting valid JSON, and that it is properly unescaped or escaped before submitting to the PHP json_decode() function. The best way to check it would be to print out the raw json string and compare them in both browsers. The php function is server side and can not be affected by the browsers, so it has to be the browser formating of the json string.